# Firefox, LibreOffice are stuck in English. I want them in Esperanto

Tags: firefox, libreoffice, language-support

I just performed a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 this week, using Esperanto since the first startup. Later I added Interlingua, but Esperanto is still second. Anyway, I noticed that Firefox was still in English and did some poking around. I found Mozilla's Esperanto language pack, as well as an add-on which changes the language in `about:config`. After installing everything and restarting multiple times, nothing has changed. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

For firefox you can get language packs and I just checked - they do have Esperanto.  Same thing for libreoffice.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/language-tools/

Comment: I mentioned that I had the language pack in my question

Answer (score 0):

Go to *System Settings* -> *Language Support*. Esperanto must be the first language in the list. Second isn't good enough for Firefox and LibreOffice.

*Edit:*

An alternative way to control the display language of an application is to use a simple wrapper. Firefox example:

```
$ cat ~/bin/firefox
#!/bin/sh
export LANG=eo.UTF-8
exec /usr/bin/firefox "$@"
```

The executable bit needs to be set:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/firefox
```

Comment: Thanks Gunnar,

But is there no way to do this by keeping Esperanto as the second language? I just checked about:config again, and general.useragent.locale is definitely set to eo, and I do have the language pack

Comment: @JacobJacob: Well, there is. I don't know what the general.useragent.locale setting is for, but I know that the display language of Firefox and LibreOffice is controlled by the LANG environment variable. Just edited my answer to show you a way.